# remove HTML from a string (in JSON response)

Tags: javascript

```
var json = {
    "Item": {
        "Items": {
         "Body": "<SPAN style=\"LINE-HEIGHT: 115%; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 11pt; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA\">\"We have all been inoculated with Christianity, and are never likely to take it seriously now! You put some of the virus of some dreadful illness into a man's arm, and there is a little itchiness, some scratchiness, a slight discomfort, disagreeable, no doubt, but not the fever of the real disease, the turning and the tossing, and the ebbing strength. And we have all been inoculated with Christianity, more or less. We are on Christ's side, we wish him well, we hope that He will win, and we are even prepared to do something for Him, provided, of course, that He is reasonable, and does not make too much of an upset among our cozy comforts and our customary ways. But there is not the passion of zeal, and the burning enthusiasm, and the eagerness of self-sacrifice, of the real faith that changes character and wins the world.\"<B>A.J. Gossip<\/B><\/SPAN>",
        },

    }
};
var someString = json.Item.Body.replace(/<br\s*\/?\s*>/g,"\n");   
alert(someString);
​
```

I am getting `HTML` tags in my response, which i should remove or parse it. How can i go about this. I did for `BR` tags, but now it seems there are other tags too coming in.

Comment: If you just want to "slap the markup in the DOM" then jQuery (or direct innerHTML tricks) should work -- *but* bear in mind possible *injection attacks* for non-controlled sources. If you want to take the HTML and turn it into something else .. well, what do you have (and *why*) and what do you want? :)

Comment: Now, what do you want - parse or remove? Or parse to remove them? Where and for what do you need the result?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think all you need is a simple regex to strip html style tags from the content. Try this.

```
str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '')
```

Comment: the `i` is redundant, right? not a big deal but the extra "check upper and lower case" on lots of checks would add up

Answer (score 1):

This should do the magic http://jsfiddle.net/Ygfvp/
Anyway it won't strip the html comments

Comment: the Segu one will. `/<\/?[^>]+>/gi` (with the escaped slash)

Answer (score 1):

If you're mapping Json using React, then you can just leave the html tags and put them to use.

**Instead of:**

```
<div>{el.content.rendered}</div>
```

**Do this:**

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: el.content.rendered}}></div>
```