# In Angular.js need to remove a specific string

Tags: angularjs

I need to remove all br tags from the json data I am working with before rendering to the template.
Im wondering if there is a pre-existing angular directive which could be used for this, or if there is a way to do it by creating a custom filter. The documantation on filters doesnt seem to be easily adaptable to this usecase.

Comment: Im not trying to sanitize out any html. I am trying to specifically remove br tags, while leaving all other html.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to remove <br>s from a specific object property like [remove HTML from a string (in JSON response)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784703/remove-html-from-a-string-in-json-response) or do you need to remove them from all properties of the JSON object?

You should be able to just put some JavaScript code into a [custom filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters) (the custom filter would return either a modified JSON object or a new object), and then call that filter from your HTML when you want to display the JSON.

If you are displaying different parts of your JSON object using different ng-repeat, ng-show, etc. directives, it might make more sense to filter the JSON once in your controller, then use the filtered version in the HTML/template.  A little more information about your actual use case would help.

Comment: I am removing br from two specific objects properties. I think it could be done using replace() http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp where I would replace the br tag with an empty string. Im just not clear on the specific implementation.