# Error in JSON Serialisation with HTML Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, nsjsonserialization

I have a strange issue while getting response from SVC webservice.

I have a response as below:

[image: Response]

When I am fetching content from "**AboutOrganization**" key.

I am getting error as below:-

**Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Something looked like a 'null' but wasn't around character 324840.) UserInfo=0xc52345b0 {NSDebugDescription=Something looked like a 'null' but wasn't around character 324840.}**

I have used **NSJSONSerialization** to get data from Webservice response.

I am not sure, But getting this type of Error because JSON object contents HTML escape sequence characters as below:

[image: Image 2]

If I am right then give me solution for the same. And If i am wrong then guide me why i am getting this type of error.

Appreciate your time and help

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this the full JSON response you're getting from the web server, or just a part of it? If this is the whole data, then it does not look like regular JSON, since it would at least start and end with curly braces (`{`, `}`). Also, can you show us the code you're using to decode the JSON response?

Comment: This is part of JSON Object. I have validate Full JSON Object and it's good.

Comment: @Er.ShreyanshShah your web service can remove the html tag or also u try this thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784703/remove-html-from-a-string-in-json-response