# Remove all HTML tags *AND* content from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, regex

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11784989/815929) solution - `str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '')` - which removes the HTML tags from json response.

```
{"fdfd":4}<p>fdfdf</p> -> {"fdfd":4} fdfdf
```

However i want to remove all content within the HTML, script tags as well for which i am seeking a solution.
Requirement -

```
{"fdfd":4}<p>fdfdf</p> -> {"fdfd":4}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string match and keep only those characters which are inside `{}`

```js
var str = '{"fdfd":4}<p>fdfdf</p>'
var m = str.match(/{(.*)}/g)[0]
console.log(m)
```

Comment: this is also ok, is there a way to only get the first json? (example : var str = '{"fdfd":4}{"gfg":66}<p>fdfdf</p>') @brk

Comment: `'{"fdfd":4}<p>fdfdf</p>}'.match(/{(.*)}/)[0]`. Use lazy regex `/{(.*?)}/` and there is no need of `g` flag.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you have to use this regex

```js
      var str='{"fdfd":4}<p>fdfdf</p>';
      console.log(str.replace(/<[^>]+>[^\n]+<\/?[^>]+>/gi, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Added runnable code:

```js
var str = '{"fdfd":4}<p>fdfdf</p>';
str = str.replace(/<\/?.*[^>*]+>/gi, '');

console.log(str);
```