# Error: element is not assignable to type string in react

Tags: reactjs

The output that I was getting is with html tags; hence I used dangerouslySetInnerHTML to avoid that after which I am getting the error "Type '{ contents: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'string'."

My react code is as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

interface FetchImageDataState {
imageList: ImageData[];
loading: boolean;
}

export class OurTeam extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, FetchImageDataState> {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { imageList: [], loading: true }; //initialize to default

    fetch('api/Home/ourTeam')
        .then(response => response.json() as Promise<ImageData[]>)
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ imageList: data, loading: false });
        });
}




public render() {

    let contents = this.state.loading ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p> : this.renderImageTable(this.state.imageList);
    let body = { contents };
    return <div>
        <h1>Team</h1>

        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: body }} />
            </div>;
}

private renderImageTable(imageList: ImageData[]) {
    return <div className='table'>
        {imageList.map(x =>
            <div key={x.byteData} >{[x]}</div>)
    }</div>;
}

}

export class ImageData {
byteData: string = "";
}
```

Without usage of dangerouslySetInnerHTML the output of the code was desired text with html tags; and also the image tag was displayed instead of image. The detailed error is:
ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/OurTeam.tsx:41:18 
    TS2322: Type '{ dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: { contents: Element; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLProps'.
  Types of property 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML' are incompatible.
    Type '{ __html: { contents: Element; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ __html: string; } | undefined'.
      Type '{ __html: { contents: Element; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ __html: string; }'.
        Types of property '__html' are incompatible.
          Type '{ contents: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I am new to react, please help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be compicating it more than it should be the below code should work fine. use a ternary operator to check if `loading` is true and render html or JSX based on that and also best to make the call when the component mounts

```
import React,{Fragment} from 'react';   
export class OurTeam extends Component {
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { imageList: [], loading: true }; //initialize to default

}

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('api/Home/ourTeam')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ imageList: data, loading: false });
        }).catch(err=>{
         console.log(err);
         }};
  }


 render() {
    return (<div>
        <h1>Team</h1>
      {this.state.loading ?
        <Fragment>
         <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        </Fragment>  
        :
       <Fragment>
        <div className='table'>
         this.state.imageList.map(x =>
             <div key={x.byteData} >{[x]}</div>)
           </div>
      </Fragment>});
}}}
```

Comment: Hi Abdullah - I will have to use the class ImageData to fetch data from server side which is Asp.net core..

Comment: What seems to be the issue , you can do it the same way you are doing it in `OurTeam` Class

Comment: The issue is that the output is with html tags; I want it without tags... for example the output is <strong>xyz</strong> instead of bold value of xyz

Comment: i would recommend, removing html from the server rather than handling it on the frontend. but if you must take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784703/remove-html-from-a-string-in-json-response)

Comment: But there is also an image that I am supposed to display which also is shown as html tag.. 

Comment: send the data back as json with `src` of the image also included e.g `{ boldText:"xyz",ImageSrc: 'SourceOfImageHere' }` , you can then use it in React as `<img src={data.ImageSrc} />`

Comment: Earlier I was passing value as string which I changed it to pass Json parameter; but unfortunately cannot pass as separate values for text values and image as the string/json that I am passing is as below. This data is displayed as is like plain text which is the problem.. Please help me if you can guide some alternative solution.
<div className='row1'><div className='col-md-3'><a href = '#' className='member-profile'><div className='imgContainer'><img className='image' src='img.jpg' /></div><span>Ashok</span><h4><span>123123123</span> ashok@test.com</h4></a>.......

Comment: It is working now; the change I did was :

imageList.map((x,index) =>
                   <div key={index} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.convertToHTML(x)} />)



  convertToHTML(x) {
        return { __html: x };
    }


Thank you Abdullah for your continuous support